# Mergerfs error: the file is of an unknown type

Tags: partitioning, mount, 22.04, raid, fstab

I'm configuring snapraid and mergerfs, with the first one I have no problems, and for the second I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9e46pz5Seo4

However, even after the reboot the error persists.

O.S.: Ubuntu 22.04

Image error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8LRC.png

Follow my fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.

#

# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a

# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices

# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).

#

# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>

# / was on /dev/sda7 during installation

UUID=2949778e-7923-4028-b642-292dfc5a5211 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1

# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation

UUID=CC88-98D2 /boot/efi vfat umask=0077 0 1

# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation

UUID=aaa16e47-967e-4022-b586-e3146d655631 none swap sw 0 0



#Fotos (/dev/sdc1) (1TB)

UUID=965cca97-3409-49a4-a559-1a52200b3cae /media/Fotos ext4 defaults 0 0



#Cursos (/dev/sdb1) (2TB)

UUID=051df214-7ef5-4201-bf5f-554c276b6429 /media/Cursos ext4 defaults 0 0



#parity (/dev/sdd1) (6TB)

UUID=b88cf37f-d214-4924-9622-576fb3e24d84 /media/parity ext4 nofail 0 0



# mergerfs

/media/Cursos:/media/Fotos /media/pool/ fuse.mergerfs cache.files=off,dropcacheonclose=true,category.create=mfs,fsname=pool,nonempty 0 0
```

df-h returns:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           2,0G  5,2M  2,0G   1% /run
/dev/sda7       112G   13G   93G  13% /
tmpfs           9,8G   89M  9,7G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/sda1        96M   31M   66M  33% /boot/efi
/dev/sdc1       916G  288K  870G   1% /media/Fotos
/dev/sdb1       1,8T  3,1G  1,7T   1% /media/Cursos
/dev/sdd1       5,5T  3,1G  5,2T   1% /media/parity
tmpfs           2,0G  2,4M  2,0G   1% /run/user/1000
```